# How to hide street and building details on openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openstreetmap, react-leaflet

I'm using javascript `navigator.geolocation` to obtain current location's coordinates and then pass it to react-leaflet to add a marker on OpenStreetMap. Everyone using portal I'm developing will be able to see other users created markers.

For privacy matters, while creating such marker, how can I hide on the map details such as street and buildings? Creating a marker at locality details level would be enough.

I googled a bit on this matter and is not clear on the findings if this is something possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are probably using raster tiles it is not possible to customize their appearance. However, you can switch to a different tile source. Check out possible tile providers: https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/ .
Some of them probably look the way you want it.

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I was able to find there a tile that suits my needs: Stamen.Terrain